# TSQL Join JSON object array property

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that accepts a JSON string which I'm inserting using data from OPENJSON().

My json string contains an object that has an string array in it.

Currently I'm writing the raw json of prop2 to my table, but I'm looking for ways to join the strings in prop2with a comma delimeter and writing that to the table. so the value saved to the prop2 column would be 'val1,val2'.

What is the best way to achieve this?

some boilerplate I'm currently working with:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
{
  "value" : [
  {
    "prop1" : "val",
    "prop2" : ["val1","val2"]
  }
 ]
}'

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (prop1, prop2)
    SELECT prop1, prop2
      FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.value')
      WITH (

    [prop1] [nvarchar](256) '$.prop1',
    [prop2] [nvarchar](256) '$.prop2' AS JSON
    )
```

Thanks!

Comment: *"so the value saved to the prop2 column would be 'val1,val2'."* Don't. Store your data in a **normalised** format. `'val1,val2'` is *not* normalised.

Comment: I understand but don't care. It needs to be concatenated.

Comment: *"I understand but don't care"* well you *should* care. Storing delimited data only makes things harder down the line, not easier. You are actually better off storing JSON or XML data over delimited data.

Comment: @Larnu I need the data delimited. I understand your reasoning but in this case I don't care about best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is mentioned in the comments, storing data in a not-normalised format is not a good idea. But, if you need a solution, the following statement is an option. Just parse the `$.prop` JSON array with `OPENJSON()` and default schema and then aggregate the items with `STRING_AGG()`:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
{
  "value" : [
  {
    "prop1" : "val",
    "prop2" : ["val1","val2"]
  }
 ]
}'
```

Statement:

```
--INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (prop1, prop2)
SELECT j1.prop1, j2.prop2
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.value') WITH (
   [prop1] [nvarchar](256) '$.prop1',
   [prop2] [nvarchar](max) '$.prop2' AS JSON
) j1
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT STRING_AGG([value], ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key]))
   FROM OPENJSON(j1.prop2)
) j2 (prop2)
```

Result:

```
prop1   prop2
val     val1,val2
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It is exactly what I need!